# What is this new voice control thing Siri?

Tags: iphone, siri

What is Siri?

- Is it really only for voice control?
- Don't we already have one of those on the previous iPhones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it really only for voice control?

Think of Siri as your personal assistant. It listens to your commands, learns from your tasks & contacts & replies to voice commands.

> Don't we already have one of those on the previous iPhones?

Well, they're no longer available for the previous iPhone as the app has been taken down.

[image: Siri download]

The new, improved Siri was developed after it's acquisition by Apple, so I'm pretty sure they would have added their Patented SecretSauce(tm) and in typical Apple style, the details are a secret.

Comment: http://www.wired.com/dangerroom/2011/10/siri-darpa-iphone/